# How to update label to display a Stopwatch form another Form?

Tags: vb.net, timer, stopwatch

I have a project that there is a Form with a Timer for a stopwatch and another that has a Label to display it. From the 2nd Form, at the moment i press Accept, it sends some data to the 1st Form so the timer can work propertly. After that, from the 1st Form the Timer  is supposed to work and update the label's text of the 2nd Form. The problem is that the Label doesn't display the stopwatch, the Timer work though.

The reason I need to do this is to keep the Timer working even though the 2nd Form is closed. When It again opens it must display the stopwatch less the time that has passed.

Here is the code of the 1st Form.

```
Public startTime As DateTime
Public elapsedTime As TimeSpan

Private ReadOnly duration As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)

Private Sub tmStopwatch_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmStopwatch.Tick

    elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)

    If elapsedTime >= duration Then
        elapsedTime = duration
        tmStopwatch.Stop()
    End If
    UpdateStopwatchDisplay()

End Sub

Public Sub UpdateStopwatchDisplay()
    Dim frmAS As New frmAddSchedule

    frmAH.lblDisplayStopwatch.ForeColor = If(tmStopwatch.Enabled, Color.RoyalBlue, Color.DarkGray)
    frmAH.lblDisplayStopwatch.Text = (duration - elapsedTime).ToString("mm\:ss\.ff")

End Sub
```

And this is de other 2nd Form where is sending the data:

```
Private Sub btnAccept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAccept.Click

    Dim frmD As New frmDashboard

    frmD.startTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(frmD.elapsedTime )
    frmD.tmStopwatch.Enabled = True

    frmD.UpdateStopwatchDisplay()
    frmD.tmStopwatch.Start()

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:** What I am trying to do is a Countdown Timer of 30 minutes for a list (in Form 2). To let the user see the countdown, I want the Form 2 to display it by doing the process in  Form 1. It's like doing the process at the background and if the user closes the form 2 for any reason, the form will be able to display at the time left.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C#. Don't spam tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this in very much the wrong way. You don't need anything relating to time in the first form. The second form can take care of everything. Here's an example of using the same instance of the second form each time and displaying it by calling `ShowDialog`.

Form1:

```vb
Private dialogue As Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create the dialogue form the first time the Button is clicked.
    If dialogue Is Nothing Then
        dialogue = New Form2
    End If

    'Display the second form as a modal dialogue.
    dialogue.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    'If the second form was created, dispose it when this form is disposed.
    dialogue?.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Form2:

```vb
'Measures elapsed time.
Private stopwatch As New Stopwatch

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Start measuring elapsed time and start displaying it.
    stopwatch.Start()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Display the elapsed time.
    Label1.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    'Don't measure or display elapsed time when form is not displayed.
    stopwatch.Stop()
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

The second form will now measure and display its own elapsed time. The stopwatch is paused whenever the form is not displayed.

Things will be slightly more complex if you want to call `Show` rather than `ShowDialog`, because closing that form will dispose it and require a new one to be created next time you want to display it. If that's what you want, let me know and I'll extend the example.

EDIT:

In order to use `Show` rather than `ShowDialog`, there are some other changes that need to be made. As the same instance will not be used each time, we need some mechanism for remembering the elapsed time in between. There are a few options for specific implementations but the simplest is to just make the `Stopwatch` object `Shared`. That way, every instance will use the same `Stopwatch` and thus the elapsed time is the same for every instance:

Form1:

```vb
Private dialogue As Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If dialogue Is Nothing OrElse dialogue.IsDisposed Then
        'Create and display a new dialogue.
        dialogue = New Form2
        dialogue.Show()
    Else
        'Set focus to the existing dialogue.
        dialogue.Activate()
    End If
End Sub
```

Form2:

```vb
'Measures elapsed time.
Private Shared ReadOnly stopwatch As New Stopwatch

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Start measuring elapsed time and start displaying it.
    stopwatch.Start()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Display the elapsed time.
    Label1.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    'Don't measure or display elapsed time when form is not displayed.
    stopwatch.Stop()
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

In that case, it is technically possible to create multiple instances of `Form2`, although the code in `Form1` is written such that only one instance will be created at a time. You can actually implement `Form2` as a *Singleton*, which means that it wouldn't be possible to create multiple instances:

Form1:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create and display a new instance or focus the existing instance.
    Form2.Instance.Show()
    Form2.Instance.Activate()
End Sub
```

Form2:

```vb
'Measures elapsed time.
Private Shared ReadOnly stopwatch As New Stopwatch

'The one and only instance of the class.
Private Shared _instance As Form2

'Make the constructor Private so that an instance cannot be created externally.
Private Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

'The one and only instance of the class.
Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As Form2
    Get
        'If there is no current instance or the current instance has been disposed, create a new instance.
        If _instance Is Nothing OrElse _instance.IsDisposed Then
            _instance = New Form2()
        End If

        Return _instance
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Start measuring elapsed time and start displaying it.
    stopwatch.Start()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Display the elapsed time.
    Label1.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    'Don't measure or display elapsed time when form is not displayed.
    stopwatch.Stop()
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: I implemented what you said and it didn't work. Also I added more information to the post.

Comment: *"It didn't work"* is never an adequate description of anything. You need to explain exactly how it didn't fulfill your expectations. If the issue is just that you want to display time remaining rather than the time elapsed then you simply do s subtraction, e.g. `remaining = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) - elapsed`. If that's not what you mean then I don't understand the question, so you should do a better job of explaining the issue. You clearly assume that we'll get the gist from the code but the code is bad so it's hard to know the exact intention.

Comment: Hi, I hope you're doing well. I misunderstood your example and it works perfectly, I was wondering if you could still help me with this because I want to display it using  `Show`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added some code examples calling `Show` and using different instances each time rather than `ShowDialog` and the same instance.